# Use java regex to validate ID with characters and numbers

Tags: java, regex

i want to validate a ID.ID look like this `POLxxxx`. here ID can contain `POL or MAN or NAY`. `x` must be `0 or 1`.as a example,

`POL0111` is correct.

`MAN0011` is correct.

`NAY0111` is correct.

`SAQ0111` is incorrect.

`MAN0221` is incorrect.

below is my tried code

`boolean x=l.matches("(?:POL|MAN|NEY)\\d[0,1]");`

i want to get true if this is correct.bit i get false to `POL1101`.help me to solve this.thank you.

Comment: `"(?:POL|MAN|NAY)[01]{4}"` Was that supposed to be `NAY` or `NEY`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried this : `(MAY|NAY|POL)[01]{4}`

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/7CgVgF/2)